# Need separate columns that calculates percentage

Tags: postgresql, count, sum

I have the following table:

```
NAME
------
Alex
Bob 
Bob
Tim
Alex
Roger
```

I need to produce the following:

```
 Name    Count Percentage
 -------------------------
 Alex    2     33%
 Bob     2     33%
 Roger   1     16.6%
 Tim     1     16.6%
```

I have no idea where to start. I can do the initial query for the count which is simple.